# Operations for Long and Float in Python

Tags: python, floating-point, scipy, long-integer

I'm trying to compute this:

```
from scipy import *
3600**3400 * (exp(-3600)) / factorial(3400)
```

the error: unsupported long and float

Comment: an error occurs. instead of the output.

Comment: we understand that *error occurs*, you wouldn't be writing here if everything went fine, would you?

Comment: are you going to tell us the error?

Comment: unsupported operand type long and float.

Comment: @wildfire: please do not provide information int he comments on your own question.  Please *update* your question with the error you're getting.

Answer (score 3):

Try using logarithms instead of working with the numbers directly. Since none of your operations are addition or subtraction, you could do the whole thing in logarithm form and convert back at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Computing with numbers of such magnitude, you just can't use ordinary 64-bit-or-so floats, which is what Python's core runtime supports.  Consider [`gmpy`](http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/) (do **not** get the sourceforge version, it's aeons out of date) -- with that, `math`, and some care...:

```
>>> e = gmpy.mpf(math.exp(1))
>>> gmpy.mpz(3600)**3400 * (e**(-3600)) / gmpy.fac(3400)
mpf('2.37929475533825366213e-5')
```

(I'm biased about `gmpy`, of course, since I originated and still participate in that project, but I'd never make strong claims about its *floating point* abilities... I've been using it mostly for integer stuff... still, it **does** make this computation possible!-).

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the [Decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) object.  Calculations will be slower but you won't have trouble with really small numbers.

```
from decimal import Decimal
```

I don't know how Decimal interacts with the scipy module, however.

This [numpy discussion](http://www.mail-archive.com/numpy-discussion@scipy.org/msg17213.html) might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Well the error is coming about because you are trying to multiply

```
3600**3400
```

which is a long with

```
exp(-3600)
```

which is a float.

But regardless, the error you are receiving is disguising the true problem. It seems exp(-3600) is too big a number to fit in a float anyway. The python math library is fickle with large numbers, at best.

Comment: actually exp(-3600) is a very small (close to zero) number

Comment: I believe you mean 3600**3400 is too big a number to fit in a float anyway.  btw, math.exp(-3600) == 0.0

Answer (score 0):

exp(-3600) is too smale, factorial(3400) is too large:

```
In [1]: from scipy import exp

In [2]: exp(-3600)
Out[2]: 0.0
In [3]: from scipy import factorial

In [4]: factorial(3400)
Out[4]: array(1.#INF)
```

What about calculate it step by step as a workaround(and it makes sense
 to check the smallest and biggest intermediate result):

```
from math import exp
output = 1
smallest = 1e100
biggest = 0
for i,j in izip(xrange(1, 1701), xrange(3400, 1699, -1)):
    output = output * 3600 * exp(-3600/3400) / i
    output = output * 3600 * exp(-3600/3400) / j
    smallest = min(smallest, output)
    biggest = max(biggest, output)
print "output: ", output
print "smallest: ", smallest
print "biggest: ", biggest
```

output is:

```
output:  2.37929475534e-005
smallest:  2.37929475534e-005
biggest:  1.28724174494e+214
```